# How Can I run testing code from Chromium

Tags: c++, google-chrome, audio, webrtc, chromium

I am working on some university project connected with WebRTC. When I was looking for audio quality test for WebRTC, I' found this:

http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2013/11/webrtc-audio-quality-testing.html

and the finished code is here:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/browser/media/chrome_webrtc_audio_quality_browsertest.cc&q=chrome_webrtc_a&sq=package:chromium

How Can I run this code to execute my test cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

steps to install are at http://www.webrtc.org/reference/getting-started
which are OS specific

Comment: Thank you! How can I miss that :).